# How to change the texture of rectangular node to another texture after a certain operation?

Tags: anylogic

I am working on a model, where I need to change the texture of node to earth texture.

The initial texture is grass (See image). I tried using

[image]

node.setFillColor(sand);

But error pops up

Comment: oh and quick aside: if you get errors, it is a good idea to share them, see some tips here: https://benjamin-schumann.com/blog/anylogic-stackoverflow

Comment: It worked. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were almost right, but you need to start using code-complete for *everything*, this avoids you typing things AnyLogic does not understand.

In your case, this will work:
[image]

*Never* type anything by yourself. Always use code-complete :)